# How do I make KDE open mail links to a webmail client in a browser?

Tags: kde, browser, user-default

I use webmail,specifically gmail. How do I make it so that when I click a mailto: link it opens gmail, in a browser (chromium) with the email address, in KDE?

*bonus points for listing other browsers and other popular webmails*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the same basic instructions in [phunhehe's post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/how-do-i-make-kde-open-mail-links-to-a-webmail-client-in-a-browser/3472#3472) except instead of `xdg-open` you can use `kioclient exec https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=%t&su=%s&%u`. This will open the same browser that you've set to default in kde.

Answer (score 4):

I found a Mozilla's support [page](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Changing+the+e-mail+program+used+by+Firefox#KDE), and a [thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=0b8a4badbeaa646f&hl=en&fid=0b8a4badbeaa646f00048103d403a02a&hltp=2) in Google's support forum. Add up with a little guessing of my own I have something that may work.

Just follow the following instruction for KDE (taken from Mozilla), with your "email client" being `xdg-open "https://mail.google.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url=$s"`

> 1. Open the KDE Control Center by clicking on K and selecting Control Center.
> 2. In the Control Center window, click to expand KDE Components.
> 3. Click to select Component Chooser.
> 4. Click to select Email Client.
> 5. Click to select the Use a different email client radio button.
> 6. Type the full path to your e-mail client (e.g. /usr/bin/thunderbird).
> 7. Click Apply to close the Control Center window and save your changes.

I don't have KDE so I cannot test, but executing `xdg-open "https://mail.google.com/mail?extsrc=mailto&url=$s"` in a terminal does open a browser with Gmail.

Tell me if it works :)