# Opening links outside of broswer in kubuntu opens html from local kde cache only

Tags: kde, kubuntu

I have this odd problem where whenever a link is opened from the shell, the cached html is opened locally, instead of through a browser.

**to illustrate**:

if I run the command `xdg-open http://www.google.com` in a bash prompt, this url opens in my browser bar: `file:///var/tmp/kdecache-seldon/krun/13954_0_`.

Here is an image of how it loads in chromium (which is currently set as my default browser).

[image: weird error]
.

---

This issue also happens when there is a call to open a link from (most) applications, for instance, clicking on an external link in the help documentation for Gwenview.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be happening? Anything I can try to keep this from happening?

---

*Updating with some steps that I have tried:*

- launching a url with the application path works just fine (i.e. `chromium-browser http://www.google.com` or `firefox http://www.google.com`
- I checked `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and thought I had actaully found the problem because `text/html` was pointed to an old, non-existent `.desktop` file. But fixing the entry to `chromium-browser.desktop` did not fix the problem

I am still at a loss for what this issue could be

Comment: this is a known [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=297491). Check if any of the solutions posted in the bug tracker works for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Im not entirely sure what goes on behind the scenes in KDE but it appears that chrome was not getting the url as a parameter, it was getting the fetched html instead (and only the html, no other resources).

So based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3472/8263) for getting web based email as your default in KDE, on a hunch, I added `$s` to the end of the default Web Browser component, and it worked. I would love to know more about the `$s` parameter, if anyone knows, but it fixed this specific issue.

**to fix this issue**: In *System Settings*, under *Default Applications* for *Web Browser*, I changed `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` to `/usr/bin/chromium-browser $s`

(*obviously `/usr/bin/chromium-browser` should be changed to the path of whichever browser you use*)

Comment: +1 Thanks - this also worked for me.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I didn't make the same change, but I saw that my Default Browser was getting the wrong path.

Solved on Arch Linux.

Comment: I have FF and Chrome installed. Changed the setting to FF since that's my default and it worked. Didn't know about this setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, For firefox nightly, I had to add `%u` to the end of the desktop file for the url to opened and not a cached file

[image]